# integral involving upper incomplete gamma function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, improper-integrals

I trying to evaluate the following integral

$$\int_0^\infty 
\dfrac
{  x^{m-1}  \Gamma(A,\mathcal B x^q)}
{\left[1+(\eta x)^n\right]^p}
\,\mathrm dx$$

where the integration is w.r.t. $x$, and the other parameters are real positive.

Any idea?

FYI: with some change of variable, the following integral might be simpler to evaluate:

$$\int_0^\infty
\dfrac
{z^{\widetilde{m}-1}    \Gamma(A,z)}
{\left[      1+(\tilde \eta z)^{\widetilde n}       \right]^p}
\,\mathrm dz$$

Comment: By letting $t=\dfrac1{1+(ax)^n}$ , we have $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{^{m-1}}}{(1+(ax)^n)^p}dx=\frac{B\big(p-\frac mn;\frac mn\big)}{n\,a^m}$

Comment: but did you consider the incomplete upper gamma function? please see my edit, that might help in someway.