# Integral with the incomplete upper gamma function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, improper-integrals

Can anyone help me integrate this?

> $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^{1/p}} \left[\frac{1-x^{1/p}}{x^{1/p}} \right]^{m/n-1} \Gamma\;\left(A, \left[\frac{1-x^{1/p}}{x^{1/p}} \right]^{1/n}\right) \,\mathrm{d}x,$$

where $p$, $m$, $n$ and $A$ are real and positive, and $\Gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the incomplete upper gamma function.

Comment: Where does this come from ? Is the value $p=1$ possible ? What have you tried already ?

Comment: This came from:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668236/integral-involving-upper-incomplete-gamma-function?noredirect=1#comment1404725_668236 after some change of variables...p can be any real positive number, including 1

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\int_0^1\dfrac{1}{x^\frac{1}{p}}\biggl(\dfrac{1-x^\frac{1}{p}}{x^\frac{1}{p}}\biggr)^{\frac{m}{n}-1}\Gamma\biggl(A,\biggl(\dfrac{1-x^\frac{1}{p}}{x^\frac{1}{p}}\biggr)^\frac{1}{n}\biggr)dx$

$=\int_0^1\dfrac{1}{x}\biggl(\dfrac{1-x}{x}\biggr)^{\frac{m}{n}-1}\Gamma\biggl(A,\biggl(\dfrac{1-x}{x}\biggr)^\frac{1}{n}\biggr)d(x^p)$

$=\int_0^1px^{p-2}\biggl(\dfrac{1-x}{x}\biggr)^{\frac{m}{n}-1}\Gamma\biggl(A,\biggl(\dfrac{1-x}{x}\biggr)^\frac{1}{n}\biggr)dx$

$=\int_\infty^0\dfrac{px^{\frac{m}{n}-1}\Gamma(A,x^\frac{1}{n})}{(x+1)^{p-2}}d\left(\dfrac{1}{x+1}\right)$

$=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{px^{\frac{m}{n}-1}\Gamma(A,x^\frac{1}{n})}{(x+1)^p}dx$